# django (under mod_wsgi) and php

Tags: php, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

Under my debian copy, I run a django site runs via apache2 and mod_wsgi. Now I want to include a wordpress to it, for that I need to install php - apache bindings. I am curious what library is recommended for this, aswell as how shall I be doing the apache2 config file ?

Here is my current apache 2 000-default file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /media /home/myuser/myproject/statics
Alias /favicon.ico /home/myuser/myproject/statics/pic/favicon.ico
Alias /robots.txt /home/myuser/myproject/templates/robots.txt
Alias /admin_media /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.5.egg/django/contrib/admin/media

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myuser/myproject/myproject_wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject user=myuser group=myuser threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to add Wordpress to  my www.mysite.com/blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debian package [`libapache2-mod-php5`](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/libapache2-mod-php5) will install the php5 bindings for Apache 2.2.

This should also set things up (in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load` or `php5.conf`) so .php files are executed by Apache's PHP handler.

Then, it's a matter of installing WordPress somewhere and adding an `Alias` to its directory.